# Can I use Majora's Mask?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

If you look in Link's house in *The Legend of Zelda: A Link Between Worlds* you can see `Majora's Mask` on the wall. Is there a way to interact with it? Or wear it?

Comment: that would probably just be aesthetic, timeline fuel

Comment: Here's a claim that it has a special feature (I don't have the game, so I can't verify or give more explanation): http://www.reddit.com/r/3DS/comments/1r9diz/i_merged_with_the_wall_near_the_majoras_mask_and/

Comment: Yep, there's totally a Skull Kid laugh. Creepy.

Comment: @ratchetfreak "timeline fuel"? Shouldn't that be "canon fodder" surely? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can merge with the wall it's on, and you sometimes hear a laugh sound in the music (some people say it is the Skull Kid laugh, but it has been so long since I have played Majora's Mask that I forget what he sounds like).

Other than that, there doesn't really appear to be anything you can do. I tried hacking at it, and bombing it, but you can't use items in your house, so nothing happens.